# Create mp3 from mic audio input

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a Mac app communicating with a web service that can only deal with mp3 files. I found out after hours of debugging that kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3 is decode only. So, I need to either take the resulting audio data and convert it straight to mp3 or convert it to AAC or some other supported format to mp3. Compatability with iOS is not a concern.

Also, please don't recommend LAME the license is not acceptable for this particular case. And any code demos would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MP3 is a patented file format. You can't just write an MP3 encoder and stick it in your app unless you pay a licensing fee.

http://mp3licensing.com/royalty/

Your best bet is to stick with the built-in AAC encoding.

Comment: Hmm.... is there no OS mp3 compatible alternative, meaning something possibly less efficient but able to be decoded as though it were mp3?

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing, but I can't definitively rule it out either.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am accepting your answer, since I think it would be best to either sell the GPL or ask the backend guy about some other format. Translation: your answer is the only 'right' one :)

Comment: Just had a random thought. Maybe you could use Apple Events to get iTunes to convert your audio into MP3?? It's a long shot but it might work. iTunes has all the moving parts (the user can clearly initiate a "convert to MP3" action).